# GTK in C language: Replace a image from event box

Tags: c, gtk3

I'm trying replace a image from event_box but doesn't work.

When the user click in a Event box, I try remove the image from the event box and add another, but when I run just remove the image and not  add another.

```
void selecFichas(GtkWidget *casillaAtril, gpointer data){
int i;

for(i = 0; i < LETRAS; i++)
    if(casillaAtril == atrilJugador1[i]){
        Element = i; 
        break;
    }
gtk_container_remove(GTK_CONTAINER(atrilJugador1[Element]), fichasABC[coordImagen[Element][0]][coordImagen[Element][1]]);
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(atrilJugador1[Element]), casillasAtriles[Element]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure to call `gtk_widget_show()` on the image that you added?

You can open up the GTK Inspector with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> and check whether the new image is actually in there or not, and whether it is visible or not.